# The subject of 何なら一日オフにして付き合ってもいいぐらいなのに?

Tags: grammar

> 寿季「元々俺が無理を言って時間を作ってもらったんだし十分だよ」
>
> 桐葉「別に他の日でも良かったのよ？**何なら一日オフにして付き合ってもいいぐらいなのに**」
>
> 寿季「それは願ってもないプレゼントではあるけど、どうしても今日が良かったんだ」

Does the bold sentence mean "If necessary, I would take a whole day off to accompany you"? Or "If necessary, you would take a whole day off to accompany me"?

It seems to be the former, but the てもいい suggests the subject should be "you". So I’m confused.

Answer (score 3):

してもいい indeed can be used to talk about actions taken/things done by the speaker or the listener, but if it refers to the listener's action in the declarative, it's usually a grant of permission. Like this line:

> そう思いたいなら、そう思ってもいいぞ
> Free feel to think that, if that's what you want to think.

> もう来なくてもいいよ
> You don't have to come anymore. *or* We don't want you to come anymore.

Note that it doesn't always have to be permission seeking or granting. A lot of times it is used to talk about a condition, but I think even in these condition descriptions, there's often an embedded benefit-receiving aspect.

> 学校行かなくてもいいなんて、羨ましいよ！
> I am envious that you don't have to go to school. (the listener has received permission from the school/parents)

Thus, it's important that you understand if there is a benefiting party between the conversing parties, and if yes, who the action potentially benefits. In your cited passage, the context makes it clear that the speaker is talking about their own action. With a rough rendering, this should be clear:

> 寿季: It was my bad. It was already a lot to ask that you make time for me.
>
> 桐葉: Would another day have been okay? If necessary, I could've just taken a day off to go with you.
>
> 寿季: I'd have liked that as well, but I needed you *today*.

Comment: +1 but your translation of どうしても今日が良かった seems off to me.

Comment: @naruto That part did give me pause! The interpretation I arrived at was that at the time of this conversation the two people are on their way to a destination they try to get to, or they have already arrived. どうしても seems to mean まちがいなく, and 寿季 is saying, "Regardless of other factors, I'm glad we decided on today." Is that not correct?

Comment: どうしても is "no matter what", and が in がいい is an exhaustive-listing-が. So "I needed you *today*", "It really had to be *today*", etc.